# Where to ask about books (or more specifically, events that happen in them)?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where can I ask about things that happen in books, similar to how you can ask about things that happen in TV shows on the [Movies and TV Stack Exchange](http://movies.stackexchange.com)?

A search for "book" in the site list only gives the [Ebooks SE](http://ebooks.stackexchange.com), which only takes questions about producing or reading e-books.

An example question might be something like:

> **Why did Alice and Bob leave the box in Examplebook?**
>   In Examplebook, Alice and Bob come across an important box. However, instead of taking it, they leave it where it was.
>   Why didn't they take it? They knew how important it was, and that they needed to take it.

Is there a site (or Area 51 proposal) where I can ask these types of questions?

Comment: If it's science fiction and/or fantasy, then [scifi.se] seems to fit the bill.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like this could be on topic on [literature](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80865/literature). It's an Area 51 proposal still in the definition phase

One of their sample questions is

> Is this passage from Madame Bovary meant to be taken completely figuratively, or is it also literally grounded?

Which is surely about the events in a book, as are various other sample questions.

Comment: I'll have to wait until it's a little more defined to see, since it doesn't say much about what qualifies as on-topic (http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/21331/guideline-principals-about-what-works-are-or-are-not-literature seems like it may get me an answer), but other than that, it looks like it fits. Thanks!

Comment: Commit to the proposal and help shape what **is** on topic.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll add some sample questions now.