# Is there a site for books? Does this topic belong in Area 51?

Tags: discussion, support, area-51, site-recommendation

Is there an SE site where it would be appropriate to ask a question pertaining to a book? The thought came up because I'm searching for a book I've heard about, but I don't have much information about it that search engines will accept. Tags such as verse-identification on christianity.stackexchange.com and word-identification from english.stackexchange.com came to mind.

Comment: Related: [Where to ask about books (or more specifically, events that happen in them)?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/266143/21960)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It actually depends on the book you are looking for. At "[SicFi & Fantasy](http://scifi.stackexchange.com)", for instance, this is a pretty common case, check out, for instance, [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification).

There no such place for books in general, it will end up with a bunch of very distantly related questions. But I believe that if you ask appropriately at any other SE Site, like History, Christianity etc. you'll most probable will be welcomed.

So, no common site, no common tag but it's OK to as on relevant stack.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Pretty sure I should be heading to SciFi & Fantasy then.